# Spring batch -How to add Flow based on conditions checking

Tags: spring, spring-batch

*Based on some properties set in the properties files if(prop1=false) Then how to remove the flow processingFlow1 in the FlowBuilder ..*

```
 Flow processingFlow1 = new FlowBuilder<Flow>("ProcessingFlow1").start(ProcessingFlow1Step).build();
    Flow processingFlow2 = new FlowBuilder<Flow>("ProcessingFlow2").start(ProcessingFlow2Step).build();
```

**New Flow** 
`Flow rulesFlow = new FlowBuilder<Flow>("rulesFlow").build()`;

**Adding flow to the flowbuilder**

```
rulesFlow = new FlowBuilder<Flow>("rulesFlow").split(new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor())
    .add(ProcessingFlow1, ProcessingFlow2, ProcessingFlow3, )
    .build();
```

*My question based on some properties set in the properties files
`if(prop1=false)`
Then how to remove the flow processingFlow1 in the FlowBuilder ..*

```
rulesFlow = new FlowBuilder<Flow>("rulesFlow").split(new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor())
    .add(, processingFlow2, processingFlow3, )
    .build();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the builder as a variable and add flows dynamically based on your condition, something like:

```
Flow processingFlow1 = ...
Flow processingFlow2 = ...
Flow processingFlow3 = ...

FlowBuilder.SplitBuilder<Flow> rulesFlowBuilder = new FlowBuilder<Flow>("rulesFlow")
        .split(new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor());
if (shouldAddFlow()) { // check prop1=false in this method
    rulesFlowBuilder.add(processingFlow1);
}

Flow rulesflow = rulesFlowBuilder.add(processingFlow2, processingFlow3).build();
```